# Improve line detecting in python with PIL

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Currently I'm trying to detect white stripes with python in a image. This is the code I've already:

```
def getPoints(self, image):
        threshold = 50
        whiteMin = 100 #Minimal average of the brightness in a lane
        minWidth = 1   #Min and Max width of a lane
        maxWidth = 8

        Points = []

        loadedImage = image.convert('L').load()

        for y in xrange(239, 479, 5):
            previousBrightness = loadedImage[127,y]

            lastDown = -1
            brightness = 0            

            for x in xrange(128, 511, 1):               
                currentBrightness = loadedImage[x,y]             
                difference = currentBrightness - previousBrightness               

                if difference > threshold: #if the current pixel is brighter than the previous and the difference is bigger than the threshold, set a flag
                    lastDown = x
                    brightness = currentBrightness                    
                elif -difference > threshold:                 
                    #check if the stripe has the correct width and the average brightness is high enough
                    if lastDown != -1 and x - lastDown < maxWidth and minWidth < x - lastDown and brightness / (x - lastDown) > whiteMin: 
                        Points.append(((x - lastDown) / 2 + lastDown,y))
                    lastDown = -1
                    brightness = 0
                elif lastDown != -1:
                    brightness += currentBrightness 

                previousBrightness = currentBrightness

        return Points
```

*image* is a PIL-image-object.

I've tried several things like using the *getdata()*-command, get a pixel with *getpixel()*, crop the image first or us a numpy-array, create a copy, roll the copy and subtract it from the first array. None of theme were faster than my current version.

I know you can use for example PyPy to speed up python code but I'm asking me if I could write a faster version without them.

Has maybe someone of you a good idea or finds a bottleleck?

Comment: Can you show an example image?

Comment: you can see an example on https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9C7D225CE1619EE!119465&authkey=!AM7ARmhyjDKrd5U&ithint=folder%2c

Comment: you can look here: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I know the hough-transform and that is not exactly what I need. But i will inform me about OpenCV, thats a good idea.